# How to change orientation of the main y-axis label in charts.js?

Tags: chart.js

This is what I don't want, circled in red:

[image: Unwanted - vertically orientated y-axis label]

And, circled in green, this is what I do want:

[image: Wanted - horizontally orientated y-axis label]

That is, I simply what to change the orientation of the y-axis label so it is horizontal like all the other text in the chart.

I've looked at the [Scale Title Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#scale-title-configuration) section of the documentation, but there aren't any clues there. Also, the y-axis title is rendered on a canvas so I can't control its orientation with CSS.

So, how do I change orientation of the main y-axis label in charts.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could add a second y-axis and define it as follows:

```
{
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  },
  ticks: {
    maxTicksLimit: 3,
    callback: (value, index) => index == 1 ? 'Scale Label' : ''
  }
}
```

Please take a look at below code snippet and see how it works.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChartAxis'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'WARNINGS',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 2],
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'ERRORS',
        data: [1, 2, 1, 3],
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            stepSize: 1
          }
        },
        {
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: 3,
            callback: (value, index) => index == 1 ? 'Scale Label' : ''
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChartAxis" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: The `(value, index) => index == 1 ? 'Scale Label' : ''` code is not compatible with Internet Explorer 11. So I have changed that to `function (value, index) { return index === 1 ? 'Scale Label' : '';}`

Comment: Is there a workaround if the chart has ***two*** y-axis, so I can the orientation of both the labelStrings?

Comment: It's OK. I solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65810246/1617737 .